# Prestashop filter products by category using WebService

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop

I'm trying to use Prestashop WebService via PHP to filter products by categories but it seems that it's impossible.

How to make it? Must be something like this

```
array(‘resource’ =>’products’, ‘display’ => ‘[name]’, ‘filter[category]’ => ‘[x]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Which Prestashop version do you use ?

I managed to get products for a specific category for **v1.5.6.1** as follows:

```
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice( YOUR_SITE_URL, YOUR_API_KEY, false );

$opt = array(
    'resource' => 'products',
    'display' => 'full',
    'filter[id_category_default]' => '[8]',
    'limit' => '5'
);

$xml = $webService->get($opt);
$resources = $xml->products->children();
```

At this stage you get a products collection. You can reach properties using standard object notation ..

```
$xml->categories->category->associations->products->product
foreach ( $resources as $key => $value ) :
    echo $value->id; // product's identifier
    echo $value->price; // product's .. guess what !
endforeach;
```

You should be able to see elements exposed by reaching `YOUR_SITE/api/products?schema=synopsis`

That's fine but I've not been able to retrieve products urls yet in order to print anchors.. *Anyone ? Any suggustion ?*

Complete documentation (1.5) [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service)

Hope it will help.

**EDIT**

**Construct products URLS on the fly**

1. Make a first API call to retrieve categor(ies/y) you want and their
   datas (url slug, ids of products they own, ...)
2. Make a second API call to retrieve the actual datas corresponding to ids retrieved during the first step.

Slugs are available under the `link_rewrite` property of items collections (like categories and products). There will be as many slugs as the total of languages that have been configured from the back-end, so you may want to loop over the `link_rewrite` property to get them all and build all urls.

```
## Initialize Prestashop API
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice( YOUR_SITE_URL, YOUR_API_KEY, false );

## Getting category I want
$opt = array(
    'resource' => 'categories',
    'display' => 'full',
    'filter[id]' => '[70]', # we are interested only in one category
    'limit' => '1'
);
$xml = $webService->get($opt);
$ws_cat = $xml->categories->category;
$products = $ws_cat->associations->products->product;

## Gathering products ids to feed the second API call filter parameter
$productsIds = array();
foreach ( $products as $p ) {
    $productsIds[] = (int)$p->id;
}

## Getting products ..
$opt = array (
    'resource' => 'products',
    'display' => 'full',
    'filter[id]' => '['.implode('|',$productsIds).']',
    'limit' => '4'
);
$xml = $webService->get($opt);
$products = $xml->products->product;
if ( count($products) ) {
    $products = array();
    foreach ( $products as $value ) {
        $products[] = array(
            'id' => $value->id
            ,'catalogURL' => "{$prestashop['url']}/{$ws_cat->link_rewrite->language[0]}/{$value->id}-{$value->link_rewrite->language[0]}.html";
        );
        # There you go ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice code. This kinda works but `HTTP Error 414: URI too long`, because this way you are concatenating a *potentially huge* amont of IDs, so it will break. And incrementing the URI's size it's *obviously* not an escalable solution... and that's what you *get* for using *GET*... :/

Comment: I don't know if my code is nice. At least it is the only way I got it to work (in a clean maner). What do you call "IDs" ? Nothing but the base url + category's slug + product's slug are concatenated here. Before getting to a 2000 characters URL length [@see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers), one will surely face SEO issues and might rethink node naming rules, IMO `:/`

Comment: I just ran into the 414 because of this ` 'filter[id]' => '['.implode('|',$productsIds).']', `. Remember that `$xml = $webService->get($opt);` is transformed into a GET query ^^U

Comment: Oh yep you're right ! Then let's split products array into small chunks `:D`

Comment: Yep, that's the first thing that came to mind, but that means multiple calls (*ugh*) of arbitrary (*ugggh*) size. Also, imagine you want 100 products from category 2 with active = 1. You'd have to ask for `n` elements `filter[active]=[1]&limit=[100]&filter[id]=[1|3|5...n]` then check if you received 100 or less (say `k`). If less, make another call with limit = 100-k, and so on until you get either enough to get to the 100 total o you have no more ids to check. And forget about `order`, of course. **MORAL**: Prestashop's WS are embarrasing.

Comment: For sure Prestashop's WS is not intended to handle heavy loads/dumps. That's okey for little widgets showing few arbitrary products `:/` (or load chuncks by chunck using delayed ajax I suppose). My snippet came to life because I needed to show some products from inside a wordpress section on the same domain. By the way, what is the context of your project ? I mean why do you need to call the WS with such heavy loads ?

Comment: 30 elements is not *heavy load*. But those 30 elements come from categories that have thousands of products. So those thousands need to be dumped in the `filter[id]` field because you can't know beforehand which will be the first 30 to satisfy the filters/order defined, can you? `:/`. If you are interested, I explained my context better in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600346/restomancy-getting-many-products-from-category-in-prestashop-1-5

Comment: What I mean is that it doesn't matter how much products you *ask* for, if it's `limit: 4`or `limit: 30`. When your category number 70 grows big enough, you code will fail in the same way, it depends on the size of the `$productsIds` array (and partly the size of each ID), since it still has to concatenate **every** element on the array in the query, you see? `^^U`

Comment: Hard to follow-up in comments `^^`. I don't remember how to (if one can) filter products ids returned in the result (like with some creation date constraint) , probably because both the API itself and its documentation are terrible `:(`